# Localization of kturtle

Tags: packaging, internationalization

I'm trying to localize kturtle in bengali... But I found the way very difficult to start it. Please suggest some easy way(IDE-which is used to debug or edit the source code). Where I can find the source code?

Answer (score 1):

KDE applications like the one you mentioned are translated by KDE, not by Ubuntu. Please see http://i18n.kde.org/ for help with all of the questions I'm sure you will have.

You can try installing `lokalize` to assist you with translation once you get the source code